# Auto -Layout UIView for both Retina and non-retina views

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

[image: UIView with non retina or 4" retina version.]

I try to put UIView at to bottom of my UI. When i put everything seems to fine , except when i check it with Retina Form Factor the UIView sticked in bottom but height is increased than normal layout:

[image]

How can i set UIView with auto-layout for both retina 4 and non retina Screen Size. Also UITextField and other UI  Objects  have no problem with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your Auto-Layout constraints in a way that accommodates both screen sizes.

In the case of the view you're showing here, adding a **height constraint** in interface builder to the view should take care of that problem.

Adding a height constraint will make sure that whatever screen size is being used, that view will remain at a constant height.